# A binomial random number generating algorithm that works when n*p is very small

Tags: binomial-distribution, random-variable, simulation, algorithms

I need to generate binomial random numbers:

> For example, consider binomial random numbers. A binomial random
>   number is the number of heads in N tosses of a coin with probability p
>   of a heads on any single toss. If you generate N uniform random
>   numbers on the interval (0,1) and count the number less than p, then
>   the count is a binomial random number with parameters N and p.

In my case, my N could range from 1*10^3 to 1*10^10. My p is around 1*10^(-7).

Often my n*p is around 1*10^(-3).

There is a trivial implementation to generate such binomial random number through loops:

```
public static int getBinomial(int n, double p) {
  int x = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(Math.random() < p)
      x++;
  }
  return x;
}
```

This native implementation is very slow. I tried the Acceptance Rejection/Inversion method [1] implemented in the Colt (http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) lib. It is very fast, but the distribution of its generated number only agrees with the native implementation when n*p is not very small. In my case when n*p = 1*10^(-3), the native implementation can still generate the number 1 after many runs, but the Acceptance Rejection/Inversion method can never generate the number 1 (always returns 0).

Does anyone know what is the problem here? Or can you suggest a better binomial random number generating algorithm that can solve my case.

[1] V. Kachitvichyanukul, B.W. Schmeiser (1988): Binomial random variate generation, Communications of the ACM 31, 216-222.

Comment: Why not accept-reject based off a Poisson proposal?

Comment: Actually, I have a better idea (though that previous Poisson-based one could be pretty efficient, using Knuth's method to generate the Poisson). Since $np$ is small, why not simply do an "inverse-cdf" type approach directly on the binomial? Almost all the values will be zero, so it's very efficient.